# Raspberry Pi (python) Run in background and reopen print output

Tags: python, printing, background, raspberry-pi

I have learned online that there are several ways of running a python program in the background:

1. `sudo python scriptfile.py&`
2. `sudo python scriptfile.py`, then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then `bg`
3. Using `nohup`
4. Using `screen`

However, I would like to know if when doing any of the first two options, after I close and reopen SSH again, I can recover what the python program is internally printing by the `print` commands. So I run python and I start to see my print commands output, but if I close the SSH, even though the program is still running, I need to restart it in order to again see my print statements.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should never run a script with **sudo**. You could potentially destroy your system.

2) Once your SSH session is closed all processes go with it. That is unless you use `nohup` or `screen` as you have found.

Comment: I am a beginner, but I think that ff I dont, I can not use GPIO, am I right?     GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)     ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!         Everywhere I look in the internet all examples using GPIO are using sudo to call the script, please let me know if there is a different way. Also, any idea about my original question? Thank you very much